# Konvajs/Vue-konva add Text/Label to each of the created Rect shape

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, konvajs, konva, vue-konva

I am using `Konvajs/Vue-Konva` within my `Vuejs/Nuxt` application. Using `Konva` I am creating the `Rect` shape dynamically at run time. I would like to know if there is a way to add a `Text/Label` within each of the shapes. I want to add a name to each of `Shape` so as to identify each of the `Shape` separately.

I have added my code sample here in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-merkle-vcmku?file=/pages/index.vue).

Can someone please let me know how can I add the `Text/Label` to each of the `Rect/Shape` that has been created using `Vue-Konva`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Konva.Group](https://konvajs.org/docs/groups_and_layers/Groups.html#page-title) to organize several shapes into structures.

```js
<v-group
  v-for="rec in nodeArray"
  :key="'node' + rec.id"
  :config="{
    x: Math.min(rec.startPointX, rec.startPointX + rec.width),
    y: Math.min(rec.startPointY, rec.startPointY + rec.height),
  }"
  @click="showEventInfoModal(rec.name)"
>
  <v-rect
    :key="'node' + rec.id"
    :config="{
      width: Math.abs(rec.width),
      height: Math.abs(rec.height),
      fill: 'rgb(0,0,0,0)',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 3,
      draggable: true,
    }"
  />
  <v-text
    :config="{
      text: rec.name,
    }"
  />
</v-group>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This really helped me, I am facing some issues with creating the `Connectors` to connect the created `Rect Shapes`. Can you please let me know how to achieve this? Any help would be really beneficial for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69856925/7584240