# Konvajs/Vue-Konva connect the shapes using the connector dynamically

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, konvajs, konva, vue-konva

I am using `Konvajs/Vue-Konva` within my `Vuejs/Nuxt` application. Using `Konva` I am creating the `Rect` shape dynamically at run time. Now I would like to use some sort of `Connectors` to connect the different `Rect Shapes` so that I can have the logic of which is `source Rect` and which is `Target Rect` so as to build the `Parent-Child` relationship.

I am creating the `connectors` using the same approach as `shapes` but for some reason, it is not working as expected.

I have added my code sample here in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-merkle-vcmku?file=/pages/index.vue).

I am looking to build something like this, where I can draw the `Nodes/Shapes` and connect them using some sort of `Connectors` with Labels. Can someone please let me know how can I add the `Connectors` and build the logic to understand `Rect/Shape` that has been created using `Vue-Konva`

[image: CPT2111081318-1890x906]

Comment: Konva is a 2D drawing library. It supports simple shapes which can be combined to create sophisticated displays. But it does not have the concept of a connector. Nor do shapes have the concept of connection points. You have to code those yourself. Or you can use a more complex lib like gojs which has more built-in diagram styles and functions. You might want to re-evaluate your capabilities vs project scope & timescale.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Thanks a lot for your response. I am actually trying to find the open-source library that can be used to achieve this. I looked into `Gojs` but it's actually a paid one and I was previously looking into `Syncfusion`. Can you please let me know if there is any open-source `drawing js library` that I can use to achieve something similar?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Really looking forward to your response. Based on your response I can use the different library if I cannot use the `Konva`.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I am really sorry for reaching out to you again but I am really stuck with this issue. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I do not want to dent your enthusiasm, but as I mentioned in the Discord, what you are trying to achieve is advanced. If we use PowerPoint as a comparison to your intended goal then you will need connection points on the shapes, variations on connectors (straight vs curved vs orthogonal) and maybe alignment hints for dragged shapes.  Given the other queries you have raised I think you are maybe new to 2D drawing and have a steep learning curve and long road ahead. SO is not a teaching site.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as it can be useful to someone else:

I tried a lot of libraries such as `Konva`, `jsPlumb Community Edition`, `Flowchart-vue`, `Vue-konva`, `BPMN` but for some reason, none worked the way I wanted it for my application.

Finally, I found an [Drawflow](https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow) library that can be used to draw `Nodes` and `Connections`.